# Python calendar, counting empty days of the week before the first of the month

Tags: datetime, date, python, strftime

I did something like this :

```
import datetime
nb_blank_days = (int(datetime.date(year, month, 1).strftime('%w'))+6)%7
```

But I doesn't looks very pythonic. Any help ?

The goal is to say that because the first of July is a friday, there is 4 blanks in the week before displaying the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just

```
datetime.date(year, month, 1).weekday()
```

Since `0` is Monday, I think this does what you want.